# Ensure processing order of new block events

Tags: web3js

How can I ensure the correct processing order of new block events when I do some await stuff in the handling code? I am afraid that the next block processing is getting started before the previous one has finished.

Is this approach valid:

```
let lastBlockTreated = Number.MAX_VALUE

web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(error, result){})
.on("data", async function(newBlockHeader){
    while (lastBlockTreated < newBlockHeader.number - 1) {await helper.sleep(1) //sleep 1 ms}       
    
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(newBlockHeader.number, true)        

    //some more await .. stuff
    
    lastBlockTreated = newBlockHeader.number            
});
```